# Is there any callback to inform me to invoke SSLRead() with standard C-Type OpenSSL?

Tags: ios, openssl

I use the GCDAsyncSocket in my iOS project. the project need to use TLSv1.3, but the GCDAsyncSocket is not supported with this version and we need to adapt iOS 9, so that is impossible to use Apple new security framework(iOS 12.2 above). I would like to use standard openssl replace the Apple security API in GCDAsyncSocket. the Apple API "SSLSetIOFuncs(SSLContextRef context, SSLReadFunc readFunc,SSLWriteFunc writeFunc)" can register the read and wirte callback, i don't find any function like this in standard c-type openssl libaray, how can i know when the data should be read with "SSL_Read()"?